# How can I run a TestNG/Selenium test suite in IE on multiple servers in parallel?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium test suite using the `IEDriver` that I run with `TestNG`. The goal is to use this test suite for regression. I want to run this test suite against each of the production servers. Currently I can point it at any of the servers and run the tests. However, the problem is that I can only run one at a time. Running them serially takes too long. Having one windows server pointed at each Linux production server is not a feasible or scalable option. I want some way to run them on separate threads, from one windows server if possible.

I have been looking into the `Selenium Grid/Remote Driver`, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution or how to implement it for my goals. From what I've read about it, I think I would want each "node" to be a different production server, but I am completely new to this technology.

I've looked around stack overflow, but I haven't found anything that quite answers my question. If anybody has experience with this sort of problem or with these technologies I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

I did implement such thing using Selenium Grid.

What you need to do is:

1. Download Selenium Server [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
2. Start a Selenium hub on one server like this:

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub
3. Start Selenium nodes on each one of the test servers like this:

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node  -hub `http://localhost:4444/grid/register`
4. Create your driver using the Selenium hub like this:

   `CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(new` `URL("http://localhost:4444/"), new URL("http://www.google.com/"),` `capabilities);`

   WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, capabilities);

More info [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) and [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: Thank you for your input. If you don't mind I've got a few questions about what you've posted. Should both the hub and the nodes be created from the same computer? Also, what arguments are you passing to the SeleneseCommandExecutor()? For example, if I have 10 servers that I want to run tests on, how would I handle that?

Comment: Also, another thing worth mentioning is that I am running these tests with the IEDriver, which cannot be run on a Linux box. Does this affect what you have told me? I am concerned because I cannot run multiple instances of IE with Selenium on one Windows machine, but I also cannot run it on the Linux box itself.

Comment: The hub and the nodes can be on different servers, for example I had one hub server with one node on it and another 5 servers with nodes. In my case I didn't need exact number of drivers, what I did need is different tests on different setups (browser and OS) so when I created a driver I just used the capabilities var to set my setup and the hub created a driver for me.

Comment: Don't worry about running IE driver. every node you register, you can specify what driver it supports (IE, firefox etc). then you just ask the selenium hub for driver with a specific setup and its gives it you from one of the nodes. (Hope it was clear enough)

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium Grid, you have:

`L`: a machine executing your Java code (your local machine or a Jenkins node).

`N`: one or more machines hosting the browser instances your tests run on.

`H`: a machine responsible for directing traffic between `L` and `N`.

When you have too many tests to run the whole suite on one machine, this is a very helpful choice. If you have your own grid of VMs, I suggest using [SeleniumGridExtras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras)--it handles some of the weirdness of IE Webdriver. If you don't, you can get set up quickly using [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) or [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/).

Even without Selenium Grid, you can run multiple test threads locally using parallel execution and increasing your thread count. (Either `threadPoolSize = 3` on a specific `@Test` annotation, or `parallel="methods" thread-count="28"` in your suite xml file.)

No matter what, though, the per-machine execution time of Selenium tests is high enough that it makes sense to run your *suites* in series. In IE it's often considered unwise to run more than one test at a time on a given machine. You can chain Jenkins jobs to have them complete one after the next after the next.